# Using Mod(%) operation with big numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, modulo

Why in JS 1000000000000000000000000000001%10 equals to 6?
I try it with calculator, it shows that mod is equal to 1.

I couldn't find any information on the Web. So could someone answer for this question?

```js
console.log(1000000000000000000000000000001 % 10);
```

Comment: Number is too big to represent accurately. Use BigInt instead.

Comment: Your number exceeds the representational capacity of a JavaScript number.

Comment: see: [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) also `%` in javascript is the remainder operator not the modulus

Comment: `1000000000000000000000000000001n % 6n` will work.